# Upper bound log likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Consider a discrete distribution $P$ on $\{0,...K\}^D$ which we can turn into a continuous distribution $p$ by adding uniform $[0,1]$ noise. Assume that we have a continuous model $q$ for $p$, we can turn it into a discrete model $Q$ by integration $\displaystyle Q(x) = \int_0^1 q(x+u)du \thinspace$  for  $\thinspace x \in \mathbb{Z}^D$. What is the mathematical way to show that the log-likelihood of the continuous model is a lower bound on the log-likelihood of the discrete model i.e. $\displaystyle E_p[log(q(x))] \leq E_P[log(Q(x))]  $

This is what I have tried so far:
using Jensen's inequality $E_p[log(q(x))] \leq log(E_p(q(x)) $
I can say that:

1) $\displaystyle log(E_p(q(x))) = log[\int q(x)p(x)dx] $

2)$\displaystyle E_p[log(Q(x))] = \int log(\int_{0}^{1}q(x+\mu)d\mu)p(x)dx  $

Isn't it enough to say that for term 2 the log is applied for part of the integral while in term one it's applied for the whole term? if it is not true what is the right way to show this?

Comment: The natural logarithm is a concave function, so  Jensen's inequality gives: $$ \mathbb{E}_p[\log(q(x))] \leq  \log(\mathbb{E}_p[q(x)]).$$

Comment: It is meaningless to compare those two expectations, because one is a log probability and the other is a log probability *density.*  The normalization to make it a density introduces an additive constant that could equal any number.